# Background video with 100% width and fixed height

Tags: html, css

I need to run a video in the background. Requirements are that the video will have to run on 100% width and 600px height/max-height. Here is what i tried to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/yydkd5t4/1/

**HTML**

```
<video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg">

<source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

**CSS**

```
#video-bg {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -100;
background: transparent url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
video {display: block;}
```

The issue what i am facing is that when i try to fix the height it also scale down the width. Any solution to my problem will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After understanding what you are trying to achieve...

You need to add a parent `div` to the video. Else it will maintain the aspect-ratio and you can't achieve what you want.

```css
#video-bg {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: transparent url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
video {
  display: block;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement('video');
</script>
<![endif]-->
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg">

    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

  </video>
</div>
```

The problem with your current code or any answers till now is that it won't maintain the `height: 600px` because the video will always maintain his aspect-ratio.

So, you add a parent `div` with `width: 100%` and a `max-height:600px` with `overflow:hidden`. This way if the video gets a bigger height it will be hidden by the parent `div`.

This is probably the best way to achieve what you want, but keep in mind it will hide some parts of the video.

Comment: I guess for that we will have to consult the video editors in which actual size we need the video so that they will provide the video of exactly the same size this way the video will not cut off.

Comment: Is there anyway to center the video so not too much of the bottom nor the top are removed?

Comment: Does anyone know it on Elementor?. As you have several parent divs on Elementor with the same code is not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yydkd5t4/3/)

Please note that I changed `min-height: 100%;` to `min-height: 600px;` and added `top: 0;`

```
#video-bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 600px;
z-index: -100;
background: transparent url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
video {display: block;}
```

Comment: Please show your code (just the relevant code would do) in your answer, if the link breaks this answer would be useless. Please consider this in future posts.

Comment: @Ruddy, if that refers to me then the code is already posted at the question and I told him what to change...

Comment: @odedta Yes that is referring to you and it does not matter if the code is at the top. Stackoverflow even had a little editor built-in so you can show the result in the answer. This makes life easier for everyone including you, its up to you if you take the advise at the end of the day but I'm sure you will soon learn what makes a good answer and what does not.

Comment: If the answer is correct and straightforward I don't think all the other information is relevant, thanks for your advice though.

Comment: **@odedta**
you did some css mistake . here you get right preview here is working .[LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/mostofa/pkxm7xgg/1/)

And @JoelAlmeida your answer really great

Comment: @MDMostofa When I opened your link I see the video is no set to 600px height, are you sure I made a mistake?