# CSS full window width background video with fixed height

Tags: css, video

I need to make a page with a full window width background video on top, a bit like airbnb.com -- but with the difference that the video should not be full screen, but rather have a fixed visible height 480 px (from bottom of video, so the video gets cropped from its top side).

EDIT TO ADD CLARIFICATION: The video should get cropped (and in this gumball solution does get cropped) from the top with all possible window widths, and additionally from the right edge with window widths smaller than 1280px (which is width of the video clip). So the video stays in original size (1 pixel in video = 1 pixel on screen) when window width is no greater than 1280px -- cropped from top edge and right edge. But when window width is greater than the video width, the video gets stretched to fill the whole width of page (1 pixel in video => more than 1 pixel on screen), and the video starts to get cropped more and more from the top edge, but no longer from the right edge at all.

I can do this with images, but videos don't react similarly to the same CSS which would cause this effect on an image.

I get close to the objective with this hack:

```
 <video id="bgrvideo" width="100%" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted poster="../video/frontpage_bgr_video_1st_frame.jpg">
    <source src="../video/frontpage_bgr_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    video#bgrvideo {
    position:   absolute;
    top:        120px;
    left:       50%;
    min-width:  100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:      auto;
    height:     auto;
    z-index:    -99;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

... and then some breakpoints for window widths wider than the original video (which is 1280 x 720):

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1350px) {
    video#bgrvideo {
    position:   absolute;
    top:        100px;
    left:       50%;
    min-width:  100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:      auto;
    height:     auto;
    z-index:    -99;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    }
    }
```

... and so on.

Then I yet added a full page wide white background at 480 px from page top, with an index higher than the video, to crop the bottom edge of video exactly at 480 px from top, even as the video may get resized slightly below that at larger window widths.

This gumball solution give otherwise an OK result, except the page gets unexplicably a horizontal scrolling bar (caused by the video tag: take away the video, and the scrollbar disappears). Scrolling the page to the right shows only a blank background, nearly as wide as the page itself.

I can get rid of the scrolling bar by disabling it, and then the page feels exactly as it should. But I don't like to sweep a problem under the carpet, I would rather find a solution which doesn't cause a horizontal scrolling bar in the first place.

So... you are welcome to scrap my gumball solution entirely, and introduce a smarter way how to make a full page wide background (or foreground) video, with fixed visible height 480 px (from bottom of video, so the video gets cropped from its top side).

Answer (score 0):

For a moment I thought that I solved the problem... but...

I found what causes the horizontal scrolling bar:

`poster="../video/frontpage_bgr_video_1st_frame.jpg"`

The poster image is not subjected to any cropping settings, and gets resized to a very large size. Removing the poster setting from video tag removes the problem of horizontal scrolling bar.

As a fallback image for the video, I now use an image sized and positioned with the same algorithm as the video (with all the breaking points), indexed under the video, so the user sees the fallback image if he cannot play the video.

Still a gumball cardhouse, but now it does the job without causing the unwanted side effect of horizontal scrollbar.

BUT SOME HOURS LATER, edit to add:

The problem came back later, even though I didn't touch this part of the page. I added some other stuff elsewhere on the page, and included two jquery libraries. Who knows what affects what. Suddenly I realized that again I have the horizontal scrolling bar, and removing the video tag removes the scrolling bar.

I don't have time for this, so for the time being I will disable the scrolling bar. But I would appreciate a better solution to all of this.

Comment: You can take a look here [Link of Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817002/background-video-with-100-width-and-fixed-height)    It will be help you to find right answer