# Video background html/css like airbnb

Tags: html, css, video

I am trying to make a video background as airbnb website, but I really can not figure it out how to make it works.
I am not sure is they use jquery or if I am missing something. In firefox looks pretty good but when I open the html in chrome, Internet explorer, Edge and safari the video is not visible. 
This is the html and css, I really hope someone can help me.
I want the video will be with the same height, I dont want it to make it responsive, just like in the airbnb, but dont know how! More than a week I am trying to make it work and nothing :(
I want to make something similar to airbnb but not the same, thats why I copy and paste the html and css code.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

HTML

```
    <div class="hero shift-with-hiw js-hero">
          <div class="hero__background">        
             <video autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" loop="loop" poster="http://dummyimage.com/320x240/ffffff/fff" class="video-playing" id="home-video">             
             <source src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/P1-background-vid-compressed-2.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>          
             <source src="https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/P1-background-vid-compressed-2.webm" type="video/webm"></source>        </video>
          </div>
          <div class="hero__content page-container page-container-full text-center">
            <div class="va-container va-container-v va-container-h">
              <div class="va-middle">
                <div class="raise-30">
                  <h2 class="text-branding text-jumbo text-contrast hero__heading">Live There</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.hero {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.hero {
    height: 600px;
}

.hero__background {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

audio, canvas, video {
    display: inline-block;
}

.hero__background video {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.hero__background video {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-container-full::after {
    clear: both;
}

.page-container-full::after {
    clear: both;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.page-container, .page-container-responsive {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
}

.page-container-full {
    width: auto;
}

.hero__content {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.hero__content {
    height: 550px;
    padding-bottom: 104px;
    top: 50px;
}

.va-container-h {
    width: 100%;
}
.va-container-v {
    height: 100%;
}
.va-container {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}

.va-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.va-top, .va-middle, .va-bottom {
    display: table-cell;
}

.text-contrast {
    color: #fff;
}
.text-branding {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text-jumbo {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: What is it that's not working, specifically? I've set up a pen [here](http://codepen.io/nickpish/pen/GqdQPo), and it seems to be working fine in the various browsers I've tried (?)

Comment: Hi! As you can see the video is responsive when I change the resolution, I dont want it to make it responsive because I have content inside the video, I would like to have the same height as in airbnb, in edge explorer dont you see two vertical black lines at the sides of the video? Thanks

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now-- you don't want the height of the video to adjust proportionally to the width; please check out the updated codepen [here](http://codepen.io/nickpish/pen/GqdQPo) and see if it reflects what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: Ok let me check, thanks

Comment: Yes you are right, I dont to be proportionally to the width, but I want to be 100 % width, and when I resize the video will be centered but with same height, as in airbnb. In Edge doesnt work :( do you think they use jquery for the video?

Comment: Ok I just updated the CodePen again after referencing [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817002/background-video-with-100-width-and-fixed-height), and I'm not seeing any issues in Edge; please check and see.

Comment: Hey its working!!! I will check what you did to make it works, but I see is working perfect. Now I am trying to remove the padding or margins around the video, you see is not 100% to the body. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes of course! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your CSS as follows:

```
.hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

.hero__background {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.hero__background video {    
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: HI again, just one thing. Do you know why the video is not centered when I resize, and also is adjusting porportionally, not always with the same height :(

Comment: Hm, are you also referencing the codepen? It all seems to be working there with the updates in the answer (?)

Comment: Yes I copy and paste, in two file .html and .css and link in the html the css but the video adjust proportionally to the width :(

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what's happening on your end- copy directly from the codepen both the markup and CSS and it should work...

Comment: Yes I already did it and when I change to a lower resolution the height change :(

Comment: Strange- I'll take another look to see what might be going on.

Comment: Do you have a link you can share?

Comment: I will try to make a link to send you